# Provisioning "things" on AWS IoT without certificates confusion

Tags: security, aws-iot, aws, certifications, provisioning

I am new to AWS IoT. I wish to use AWS IoT's feature called JITP (Just In Time Provisioning) to provision my gateways automatically. I am using BeagleBone boards as device gateways.

I followed the steps by generating and registering the CA certificate on AWS IoT etc., then generated the device certificate, associated it with a thing and got things up and running.

I just realised now that I can bypass the part to generate certificates by simply creating a "thing" and nothing more. I can still communicate with its shadow etc. What is there in place to stop "things" being created on AWS IoT without valid certificates?, which is what we would need in real life

Also, the AWS notes relating to Just-In-Time_Provisioning state that a root CA certificate must be registered first. It seems that this step can be skipped? This is confusing. Thanks in advance.